# Why does the following recursive function give the outputs 'atm' and 'hatm'?

Tags: python, recursion

I am practicing some programming problems for my upcoming exam. This is one of the practice questions I did not understand:

"What does the following code (in Python) print?"

```
def f(s):
    if len(s) <= 1:
        return s
    return f(f(s[1:])) + s[0] #Note double recursion

print f('mat')
print f('math')
```

Apparently, the answers are

```
atm
hatm
```

But why?

Comment: What do _you_ think it should print?

Comment: Step through it by hand. Indent for each recursion call.

Comment: My mistake, it should have been 'hatm'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. `f("mat") = f(f("at"))+"m" -> f(f(f("t"))+"a") +"m" -> f("ta") + "m" -> "atm"`

   - `f("ta") = f(f("a")) + "t" -> f("a") + "t" -> "at"`
   - `f("at") = f(f("t"))+"a"   -> f("t")+"a" - > "ta"`
   - `f("t") = "t"`

Comment: aha! thanks. I had a misunderstand about what s[1:] did. Now I understand :).

Answer (score 2):

```
f('mat')
f(f('at')) + 'm'
    f('at') = f(f('t')) + 'a'
        f('t') = 't'
    f('at') = f('t') + 'a'
        f('t') = 't'
    f('at') = 'ta'
f('ta') + 'm'
    f('ta') = f(f('a')) + 't'
        f('a') = 'a'
    f('ta') = f('a') + 't'
        f('a') = 'a'
    f('ta') = 'at'
'atm'
```

Answer (score 2):

To follow the flow of recursive calls, fire up a debugger, such as the cross-platform [Winpdb](http://winpdb.org/) and you'll see all calls live with their arguments.

To try and make sense of 'patterns' in the recursion, try running the function with numbers so you can visualize permutations

```
>>> print f('12')
21
>>> print f('123')
231
>>> print f('1234')
4231
>>> print f('12345')
23451
>>> print f('123456')
456231
>>> print f('1234567')
3426751
```